# GDAL translate not creating .tif when running a VRT file with Python function

Tags: gdal-translate, vrt

I've created a .vrt file using `gdal.BuildVRT()` and tried to apply a simple Python function Using Derived Bands to multiply original values (all values are 1) and then use `gdal.Translate()` to write it to a .tif file. But I can't manage it to work, no file is created, no thrown error or warning also.

My vrt file is as follows:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="11000" rasterYSize="11000">
  <SRS>PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 21S",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-57],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32721"]]</SRS>
  <GeoTransform>  4.9998000000000000e+05,  1.0000000000000000e+01,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  7.6002000000000000e+06,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -1.0000000000000000e+01</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1" subClass="VRTDerivedRasterBand">
      <PixelFunctionType>multiply</PixelFunctionType>
      <PixelFunctionLanguage>Python</PixelFunctionLanguage>
      <PixelFunctionArguments factor="1.5"/>
      <PixelFunctionCode><![CDATA[
          import numpy as np
          def multiply(in_ar, out_ar, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, raster_xsize,
                          raster_ysize, buf_radius, gt, **kwargs):
              factor = float(kwargs['factor'])
              out_ar[:] = np.round_(np.clip(in_ar[0] * factor,0,255))
          ]]>
    </PixelFunctionCode>
    <Metadata>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE">YES</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">1</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">1</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">1</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">0</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT">16.4</MDI>
    </Metadata>
    <NoDataValue>0</NoDataValue>
    <ColorInterp>Gray</ColorInterp>
    <ComplexSource resampling="nearest">
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">T21KWR_20201209_smoothed.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="11000" RasterYSize="11000" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="11000" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="11000" ySize="11000" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="11000" ySize="11000" />
      <NODATA>0</NODATA>
    </ComplexSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

In Python, I'm trying:

```
import os, gdal
image_in = '.../T21KWR_20201209.vrt'
image_out = image_in.replace('.vrt', '.tif')

gdal.SetConfigOption('GDAL_VRT_ENABLE_PYTHON', 'YES')
gdal.Translate(image_out, image_in, format='GTiff', outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte, creationOptions=['COMPRESS=LZW'])
gdal.SetConfigOption('GDAL_VRT_ENABLE_PYTHON', None)
```

Also tried:

```
os.system('gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -co "COMPRESS=LZW" --config GDAL_VRT_ENABLE_PYTHON YES {} {}'.format(image_in, image_out))
```

gdal version == 2.4.2

What am I missing?

Comment: Works for me if I indent the python code correctly - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gknj2.png

Comment: Changed indentation and it "almost" worked. gdal.Translate() started creating the file but no operation was performed on pixel values.
After changing dataType from "Byte" to "Float32" it worked properly.
Thanks @user2856